# Applying formula with changing row position to VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet that count the number of days between a designated date in column A and today() date in column B which stops the counting in column C if there is the word "CLOSED" in Column D. But I have a problem where I want to reapply back the formula if column D is blank again. I'm not sure how to make the column rows appear at the right place for the formula to be used

Below is the VBA code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Target.Cells = "CLOSED" Then
'Run only when change is made in Column D
  If Target.Column = 4 Then
   Application.EnableEvents = False
'Replace the formula with the current result
    Range("C" & Target.Row) = Range("C" & Target.Row).Value
    Range("B" & Target.Row) = Range("B" & Target.Row).Value
   Application.EnableEvents = True
  End If
 End If

  If Target.Cells = "" Then
'Run only when change is made in Column D
  If Target.Column = 4 Then
   Application.EnableEvents = False
'Replace the formula with the current result
    Range("C" & Target.Row).Formula = "=TRUNC($B2 - $A2)"
    Range("B" & Target.Row).Value = "=Today()"
   Application.EnableEvents = True
  End If
 End If
End Sub
```

I would really appreciate it if someone can teach me how to properly change the code:

```
Range("C" & Target.Row).Formula = "=TRUNC($B2 - $A2)"
```

as I am still new to VBA programming and would like to learn from my mistake

Comment: You should use FormulaR1C1 format. Your code also has potential errors.

Answer (score 2):

Below will do what you want. Learn that you can use the `.FormulaR1C1` similar to effect of filling up/down. The potential issues including more than 1 cells is changed. Have not put checks if the cells in columns A/B are empty.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim oRng As Range

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each oRng In Target.Cells
        With oRng
            If .Column = 4 Then
                If UCase(Trim(.Value)) = "CLOSED" Then
                    .Worksheet.Cells(.Row, "B").Value = .Worksheet.Cells(.Row, "B").Value
                    .Worksheet.Cells(.Row, "C").Value = .Worksheet.Cells(.Row, "C").Value
                ElseIf Len(Trim(.Value)) = 0 Then
                    .Worksheet.Cells(.Row, "B").Formula = "=Today()"
                    .Worksheet.Cells(.Row, "C").FormulaR1C1 = "=TRUNC(RC[-2]-RC[-3])"
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next oRng
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that:

- you need to act for any column 4 cell change, only
- there can be more than one changed cell in column 4

so I'd go like follows (explanations in comments):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rangeToProcess As Range

    Set rangeToProcess = Intersect(Target, Columns(4)) 'mind edited cells in column 4 only
    If rangeToProcess Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim cell As Range
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each cell In rangeToProcess 'loop through edited cells in column 4
        With cell.Offset(, -2).Resize(, 2) ' reference a 2-cells range at the left of current cell
            Select Case cell.Value 'process current cell value
                Case "CLOSED" ' if it's "CLOSED" ...
                    .Value = .Value ' ... then leave values in referenced cells
                Case "" ' if it's "" ...
                    .FormulaR1C1 = Array("=Today()", "=TRUNC(RC[-1]-RC[-2])") ' ... then restore formulas
            End Select
        End With
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @wt1155, any feedback?